# Parallel.ForAsync in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, parallel.foreachasync

I want to execute a for loop in C# in parallel asynchronously. But the `Parallel` class contains only a synchronous `For` method and an asynchronous [`ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) method (.NET 6). This looks like an oversight to me.

Where is the `Parallel.ForAsync` method? Is there any workaround?

Comment: What version of .NET are you targetting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I agree**,
not having a `Parallel.ForAsync` method looks like an enormous oversight.
I have good news for you though:
in **.NET 8** and **C#12** (coming out soon at 23. november 2023) this will be resolved.
[image: Parallel.ForAsync]

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you can't wait / use .NET 8, you can try to mimic `ForAsync` with a help of `ForEachAsync` which is supported from [.NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-7.0) on. To loop over some enumerable (array, list, etc.) while having `index`:

```
// Must be IEnumerable<T>
var data = ...;

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(data.Select((value, index) => (value, index)), 
                            async (pair, token) => {
  var value = pair.value;
  var index = pair.index;

  //TODO: relevant code here
});
```

If you want to have async version for `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)` loop then

```
int n = ...;

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(Enumerable.Range(0, n), async (i, token) => { 
  //TODO: relevant code here
});
```

Comment: As a side note a more concise syntax for getting the `value` and the `index` is [tuple deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct): `(T value, int index) = pair;`

Answer (score 2):

The [`Parallel.ForAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.forasync) API will be available starting from .NET 8 (release scheduled for November 14, 2023). It has the three following overloads:

```
public static Task ForAsync<T>(T fromInclusive, T toExclusive,
    Func<T, CancellationToken, ValueTask> body)
    where T : notnull, IBinaryInteger<T>;

public static Task ForAsync<T>(T fromInclusive, T toExclusive,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<T, CancellationToken, ValueTask> body)
    where T : notnull, IBinaryInteger<T>;

public static Task ForAsync<T>(T fromInclusive, T toExclusive,
    ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Func<T, CancellationToken, ValueTask> body)
    where T : notnull, IBinaryInteger<T>;
```

It is the first public .NET API to be based on the generic math interfaces introduced in .NET 7.

Usage example:

```
ParallelOptions options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 };

await Parallel.ForAsync(0, 100, options, async (i, ct) =>
{
   // Process the i element (here the type of i is int)
});
```

More information and benchmarks about this API can be found in [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-8/#parallel) Microsoft document. Also [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/59019) is the API proposal.